# How to use XPath to Find this locater Dynamically

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to find checkbox element with dynamic XPath, I couldn't figure it out Is there anyone can help me?

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    ***<span style="font-weight: bold;">Text Message</span>***
    </td>
   <td>
   <div id="landingzone_form:j_id_94">
    <div id="landingzone_form:j_id_95" class="ui-selectbooleancheckbox ui-chkbox ui-widget">
      <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
        <input id="landingzone_form:j_id_95_input" name="landingzone_form:j_id_95_input" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" aria-hidden="true" aria-checked="false" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;landingzone_form:j_id_95&quot;,e:&quot;change&quot;,f:&quot;landingzone_form&quot;,p:&quot;landingzone_form:j_id_95&quot;,fi:&quot;landingzone_form:j_id_94&quot;});">
        </div>
          <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            ***<span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></span>***
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to find "" this element from "***Text Message***". Thank you

Comment: I am trying to find  this element "<span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c">" from "<span style="font-weight: bold;">Text Message</span>". Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
//tr[contains(., 'Text Message')]//span[contains(@class, 'ui-chkbox-icon')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to locate the checkbox by using the css selector
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-chkbox-icon.ui-icon.ui-icon-blank.ui-c")).click();